# MVC + IIS7 = CSS Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a web site running via IIS7 on Vista. The site is running on port 88, so http://localhost:88 should render the default /Home/Index view.

This works correctly, as do all other views.

However, one problem is resident. My script paths point to /Scripts/[FILE] and my CSS paths point to /Content/[FILE]. My assumption was that the /Content or /Scripts folder would always be at the root of the site as I have no intention to run this site in a virtual directory setting. Whenever the pages render, they have NO CSS or script! So everything looks wonky and the scripting obviously doesn't work, hence a lot of the views don't work either.

This is a very odd problem, one that I'm sure is a result of my lack of knowledge hosting things under IIS7. I'd appreciate any help anyone could offer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML so that we can help you?

Comment: When I try to browse to http://localhost:88/Content/Site.css, I get an ASPX 404 error message. It seems the CSS extension is being processed by the ASPNET isapi filter (weird as all get-out!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope the continuation of this thread conveys a willingness to make sure this problem doesn't drive anyone off the cliff. There's a lot of documentation in various forums about solving this issue on Vista but I couldn't find any likewise articles for 2K8. As indicated in this [forum post](http://forums.iis.net/p/1143592/1849083.aspx#1849083) I was able to fix the issue on a Vista machine. Alas, a like execution failed to resolve the matter on 2K8.

I had verified that the StaticFileHandler had been included in the web.config [as suggested in this blog post at apijunkie.com](http://www.apijunkie.com/APIJunkie/blog/post/2007/11/Breaking-changes-in-ASPNet-20-HTTP-Handlers-when-moving-from-IIS5-on-Windows-2000-to-IIS6-on-Windows-2003.aspx). Still, no luck.

Clarifying *no luck, here* - My server-side functionality was perfect. All MVC routes work like a champ. Just all CSS and JS rendering failed. When browser pointed directly at CSS or JS files resulting page was an ASP.NET 404 and not the *traditional* 404 error page.

So I went into the IIS7 Manager and into the Handler Mappings dialog. I added a new handler that specified the System.Web.StaticFileHandler type and gave it an extension of *.CSS. Then I repeated that for *.JS, *.PNG, and *.GIF files. When I refreshed the site in the browser, everything rendered perectly. The screen shots below demonstrate this process.

The Handler Mappings Window:

[image: handler mappings]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://bradygstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/managed-handler.png))</sub>

Adding a new Managed Handler

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://bradygstorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/add-managed-handler.png))</sub>

This resolved the problem, and now I have a perfectly functioning MVC app hosted in W2K. Time for a Guinness.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Worked for me when I ran into the issue too.

Comment: Somebody can write down the steps, please. The images are down.

Comment: As much as his CSS files returned 404s, his images here do the same. :) **Always loved broken image links.**

Comment: @bradygaster: can you please reupload your images to imgurl and redirect your answer to those images? Because from the content I guess they're important.

Comment: downvoting, please do what Robert Koritnik is saying and I will upvote

Comment: SINCERE apologies for the images being down. I've enabled SO notifications, so never again shall this happen!

Answer (score 7):

From Control Panel, go to Turn Windows features on or off, then check Static Content in sub-sub-sub node of IIS.

Comment: This was my issue. I would recommend checking this first.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the way I created the application. According to the [forum thread located here](http://dev.communityserver.com/forums/t/485290.aspx), I needed to select the "Classic .NET AppPool" to fix my problem. Gotta love progress!

Comment: When I created the app pool, I left the default mode: `Integrated`... I just changed to `Classic` and seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this isn't a fix on Windows 2008. Should anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this matter it'd be appreciated.

Detailed problem:

Windows 2K8 Server, IIS7. Have pipeline turned on and static file support installed. MVC works, but CSS doesn't render.

What the heck?

Answer (score -2):

The problem not lies precisely in the authorization/authentication but in the modules that now manages the IIS.
Inside system.webServer you should have **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests** set to **false** so you can display all images/css without problems with authentication.

In ASP.NET websites, the value of **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests** previously had to be set to true to support routing. However, once **IIS 7 has been updated with a Service Pack**, the value of **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests** can be set to **false** or omitted when working with ASP.NET routing.

Ref. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules

P.S. Don't forget to add the following lines to the AppSettings section of my web.config file:

< add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />

< add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>

Comment: Please stop posting copies of this same answer. It does not apply to the questions you are posting it on.