# The ASP NET site does not shown images and css

Tags: css, asp.net, image, iis

This is my site
http://www.acoustiguidecn.com/

All the images does not appear with error 500.

The static content in the IIS is checked.

What can be the reason that all the images does not shown.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks you VDWWD One of the response worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment cause I'm below 50 rep -.- so I have to write an answer.

Maybe you didn't configure your database correctly. Maybe you have a typo in your controller.

I've had a bunch of internet server errors and it was mostly my fault. typos with  ajax or doing something stupid in the controller.

I see something I've never seen before on your website. when I Inspect your page and scroll a bit up in the error list, I see this:

> A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js, is invoked via document.write.
>   This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network
>   connectivity. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details.

Maybe it'll help.

Comment: oh you fixed it, good job :)
or atleast I think you did. I see pictures again.

Comment: what was the reason that it didnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the STATIC CONTENT from the web.config file Resolve my problem

From the above link that added by  VDWWD [IIS 7.5 no images css js showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771831/iis-7-5-no-images-css-js-showing)

[image]